# JFileChooser is throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jfilechooser

I have a swing application that is using `JFileChooser`. When I click the Open menu item from File menu it should show the File dialog box where user can select the file.

This application is running in my machine but encounters problem in another machine. File dialog box is not showing and stack trace shows that `NullPointerException` is thrown by `JFileChooser`

My machine is a 64 bit Windows 7 while the other machine is Windows 7 32 bit. Both machine are using java 1.6

To verify if its because of the 32-bit, I tried in another Windows 7 32-bit and the same application is working.

```js
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class FileChooserTester{
   

    public Boolean loadMDBFile() {
      JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
      FileNameExtensionFilter fileExtensionFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
        "*.mdb", "mdb");
      fc.addChoosableFileFilter(fileExtensionFilter);
      fc.setDialogTitle("Open");

      int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

      if (returnVal != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       return null;
      } else {
       try {
       
        // process file

       } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
       }

       return true;
      }

     }
  
  
   public static void main(String[] args) {
           new FileChooserTester().loadMDBFile();
     
     }
```

Below is the stack trace.

```
ERROR actions.menu.File_Open - Error occured while opening an existing timetable. null 
caused by null java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init><ImageIcon.java:215> 
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init><ImageIcon.java:201>  
    at sun.swing.WindowPlaceBar.<init><WindowPlaceBar.java:94> 
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowFileChooserUI.updateUseShellFolder<WindowsFileChooserUI.java:542> 
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowFileChooserUI.installComponents<WindowsFileChooserUI.java:542> 
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowFileChooserUI.installComponents<WindowsFileChooserUI.java:219> 
    at java.swing.plaf.basic.basicFileChooserUI.installUI<BasicFileChooserUI.java:145> 
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowFileChooserUI.installUI<WindowsFileChooserUI.java:152> 
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI<JComponent.java:681> 
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.updateUI<JFileChooser.java:1774> 
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setup<JFileChooser.java:371> 
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init><JFileChooser.java:344> 
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init><JFileChooser.java:297> 
    at actions.menu.File_Open.loadMDBFile<File_Open.java:221>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the advice I added a code snippet from my application.

Comment: *"..added a code snippet.."*  If I thought an uncompilable code snippet would get you better help, sooner, I'd have written that.  Follow the link, **read** about the MCVE.

Comment: Sorry if I choose a wrong word. I get a code fragment from my application then put it in a class with a main method as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely caused by this part of the code:

```
if (returnVal != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    return null;
}
```

This occurs when the cancel button or the 'X' is pressed.  If you select a file and press the "open" button, the file should be processed normally.

My suggestion is to change the return type of the method to primitive boolean, and return false instead of null.

**UPDATE**: this is the converted version of your code I used to test (troubleshoot)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter fileExtensionFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            "*.mdb", "mdb");
    fc.addChoosableFileFilter(fileExtensionFilter);
    fc.setDialogTitle("Open");

    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (returnVal != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("I am returning null!");
        System.exit(1);
    } else {
        try {

            System.out.println("Doing something");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("I am returning false");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.println("I am returning true");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is the File Dialog is not even showing and same application is running in some machines but not in other machines

Comment: It shows for me.  Try this: convert your `loadMDBFile` into your main method, and change all the returns with `System.out.println()` statements, followed by `System.exit(0)` and see what prints out when you run the code.

Comment: I just tried your code "as-is" and the Dialog shows up just the same.  The suggestion still stands:  **DO NOT** return null. In this case, there is no need to do so, when you can return `false` instead. I would also change the return type to `boolean`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually it is working in my machine. I need to return null when the user click cancel due to some program logic. Anyway, even when I tried changing it to false it is still not working on the other machine. And besides that portion of the code is not even executed. The error occurs on the call to the showDialog() method

Comment: @LauraLacsina-Sicat without complete code, this is an impossible task. Make sure that all objects inside the `showDialog()` method are properly instantiated prior to call.